# Checking for input "0" (zero) with cin

Tags: c++

I'm trying to have a program loop, accepting input and producing output until the user enters "0" as the input.

The problem is, my program accepts two values for input, like this:

```
cin >> amount >> currency;
```

So, I tried to have a while statement like this:

```
while (amount != 0 && currency != "") {
    cin >> amount >> currency;
    cout << "You entered " << amount << " " << currency << "\n";
}
```

However, the while statement always executes, even if I enter `0` as input.

How do I write the program such that it accepts two values as input except when the user enters 0, in which case it terminates?

Comment: What are data types of amount and currency? Coz If you declare them as 'int', currency!="" will be void! int comparing with char...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the fact that the right side of `&&` is not executed if the left is false:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    int amount;
    std::string currency;
    while (std::cin >> amount && amount != 0 && std::cin >> currency)
    {
        std::cout << "You entered " << amount << " " << currency << "\n";
    }
}
```

test run:  https://ideone.com/MFd48

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you do your check on the next iteration, after you've already printed the message. What you probably want is something like the following pseudo-code:

```
while successfully read amount and currency:
   if amount and currency have values indicating that one should exit:
      break out of the while loop
   perform the action corresponding to amount and currency
```

I'll leave the actual code to you, since I suspect this is homework, however here are some hints:

1. You can use `break` to prematurely exit out of a loop.
2. Your while line should look like `while (cin >> amount && cin >> currency)`

Answer (score 0):

What are the data types of 'currency' and 'amount'?
If 'amount' is of type 'char' then its integer value for '0' would be something else depending on the encoding ( 48 for ASCII ). Thus when you call 'cout << amount' you see '0' but when you evaluate 'amount != 0' it returns true instead of false.